# Modify page table entry on Windows

Tags: windows, windbg

For a stack address I have the following PDE / PTE info from Windgb:

```
    kd> !pte 6EFFC 
                VA 0006effc
    PDE at C0600000            PTE at C0000370
    contains 0000000065D39867  contains 0000000000000020
    pfn 65d39     ---DA--UWEV  not valid
                        DemandZero
                        Protect: 1 - Readonly
```

How does WinDBG find out about the readonly state if even the PTE is not valid and how can it be changed? Has to be done via VAD?

Comment: Why the term "modify" in the question title? Do you want to modify the PTE?

Comment: Yes, actually to read write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the '`valid`' bit of the PTE is not set (which is the case in your example) then the PTE is handled by the operating system, not by the MMU.

In this case your PTE is a software PTE (`_MMPTE_SOFTWARE` structure; != `_MMPTE_HARDWARE` [you can '`dt`' both structures on windbg]), which can results in 4 types of software PTE, depending on the bits set in the bitfield.

If bits 12 to 31 are all zero, then this is a "Demand Zero" PTE (thus, not resolved via VAD). Bits 5 to 9 indicates page protection (0x20 = 5th bit set = Read Only).

Protection bits are not officially documented, although you can find their values on some pages on the net. Taken from [this reactos page](https://www.reactos.org/wiki/Techwiki:Memory_management_in_the_Windows_XP_kernel):

```
#define MM_ZERO_ACCESS         0  // this value is not used. 
#define MM_READONLY            1 
#define MM_EXECUTE             2 
#define MM_EXECUTE_READ        3 
#define MM_READWRITE           4  // bit 2 is set if this is writable. 
#define MM_WRITECOPY           5 
#define MM_EXECUTE_READWRITE   6 
#define MM_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY   7 
#define MM_NOCACHE             8 
#define MM_DECOMMIT         0x10 
#define MM_NOACCESS         MM_DECOMMIT|MM_NOCACHE
```

(Note: remember you have to left shift by 5 the above constants as protection bits start at bit 5)

See this blog post "[Windows Virtual Address Translation and the Pagefile](http://rekall-forensic.blogspot.fr/2014/10/windows-virtual-address-translation-and.html)" (especially the part discussing Software PTEs) for a very good explanation about the various PTEs.

Comment: +1 "Bits 5 to 9 indicates page protection (0x20 = 5th bit set = Read Only) " , what are the other bits [6,7,8,9] represents ?

Comment: @Prakash : updated my answer with the protection bits constants.